# Conectar 2 aplicaciones en una red LAN (C# o VB NET)

Tags: c#, vb.net, socket

Hola compañeros estoy utilizando Sockets sin importar el lenguaje de programacion, tengo 2 aplicaciones(Red Lan),una en la PC y otra en una Portatil..
Quisiera saber si es necesario tener el PUERTO ABIERTO para la conexion de las 2 aplicaciones en una RED LAN ?
Que direccion necesito ocupar para que las aplicaciones se conecten ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podrian ayudar xfa :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tienes que validar es que el firewall local de windows en las pcs permiten la conexion, no es un tema de la red local ya que esta no impedira la comunicacion, pero si el fiewwall local de la pc

[How to Block or Open a Port in Windows Firewall](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/block-open-port-windows-8-firewall)

en realidad solo deberias habilitar esto en la pc que expondra el puerto para escuchar la comunicacion, o sea la parte que actuara com servidor.

Las ips que usaras son de LAN, aunque veo que implementas IPv6, por lo tanto debes validar que el socket lo soporta

[IPv6 Client Server Network Applications in C# .NET](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3588/IPv-Client-Server-Network-Applications-in-C-NET)

Comment: Pero que uso ?   127.0.0.1 ?   192.168.1.2 ?

Comment: segun la imagen tiene IPv6 no aplica ninguno de esos dos, por eso lo ultimo que comente en la respuesta, salvo que cambies la config de red y uses IPv4, 127.xxx es localhost ese no aplica

Comment: Hola Leandro tengo el mismo problema a resolver. Que es que no se como comunicar 2 terminales a traves de la red del modem WIFI. Podrias darme una mano sobre como implementarlo conceptualmente?

Comment: Hola @AxelStermann. Esta publicacion es muy antigua. Prueba a leer [ask] y formular una pregunta tú mismo. Recuerda que no puedes comentar hasta tener el privilegio (con 50 de reputacion) asi que no publiques comentarios en el apartado de respuestas. Un saludo